# Concatination of Ragged Tensors Raises Value Error

Tags: tensorflow2.0, ragged

I am following the view on [youtube here](https://youtu.be/D1c2pi624X4?list=PLQY2H8rRoyvzoUYI26kHmKSJBedn3SQuB&t=196),

it shows the code

```
text_1 = tf.ragged.constant(
    [['who','is', 'Goerge', 'Washington'],
     ['What', 'is', 'the', 'weather', 'tomorrow']])
text_2 = tf.ragged.constant(['goodnight'])

text = tf.concat(text_1, text_2)
print(text)
```

But it raises the ValueError as follows:

> ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype int32 for Tensor with
>   dtype string:

What is wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

In the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/concat) it says that concat takes a **list** of tensors and an axis as arguments, like so

```
text = tf.concat([text_1, text_2], axis=-1)
```

This raises a ValueError because the shapes of the tensors don't match. Please specify what you want to achieve.

Edit:

In the video you linked to there appears to be a syntax error in this line: `text_2 = tf.ragged.constant(['goodnight']])`. (The brackets don't match.) It should really be `text_2 = tf.ragged.constant([['goodnight']])`, which achieves the result printed below the operation in the video.

Comment: This is the point the video is making, the new datatype: tf.ragged. I included the video there.

Answer (score 0):

The `tf.concat` requires one list of tensors and a axis. And the `text_2` should have the same dimentions of `text_1`

```py
text_1 = tf.ragged.constant(
    [['who', 'is', 'Goerge', 'Washington'],
     ['What', 'is', 'the', 'weather', 'tomorrow']])
text_2 = tf.ragged.constant([['goodnight']])

text = tf.concat([text_1, text_2], 0)
print(text)
```